# Titanic module - Average age of those who did survive, didn't survive grouped by sex

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

Average age of those who did survive, didn't survive grouped by sex
Using Groupby

filtered survived, filtered age mean and filtered sex but how do i group 2 or more columns with 2 or more filters together using groupby

should i use .agg?
how should i group the columns?

Comment: you need to provide minimal reproducible sample data/ code and show us your desired output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```py
data.groupby(['is_survived', 'gender']).age.mean()
```